# upload rails app to heroku skips assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, push, commit

I am trying to upload my rails app to my heroku account **as i did a few times before(successfully)**

```
heroku login (email and pass)
    rake assets:precompile 
    bundle install --without production
    git add --all
    git commit -am "commit_desc2"
    git push heroku master
```

i get my app without all of the css and js include in the header. I think it's an assets commit issue. I don't remember doing anying different except changing the design a little using bootstrap.

here is the head on heroku

```
<link href="/assets/application-6dc3bf401e7f79f69a2a156bdeeb7a00.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/application-14e3dc5612ffc200db37e141e57c5af2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

here is the head on the localhost

```
 <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrapStyle.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/ratings.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/ratings.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development)**:

> In development mode, assets are served as separate files in the order they are specified in the manifest file.

You haven't actually asked a question, but to be clear: **your assets aren't being skipped.**

What you see (all the files listed) in localhost are being included in production (in a single `application.css` and `application.js` file.

In `config/evironments/development.rb` you have

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

This causes

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

to be expanded out, creating separate script and link tags for each of the javascript and stylesheets that will be included through your `//=require` lines via Sprockets and Rails asset pipeline.

In production (on heroku) the above debug config option is set to false, serving up a single, concatenated/compressed version of your stylesheets and javascripts.

I'm sure if you check your Javascript console for variables/methods available in any of the Javascript files you see listed in localhost's `<head>` you'll find they exist. The same goes for the contents of the application.css file in production.

**Recommended Reading:** http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: hi @Deefour, thanks for the reply. after clicking on the `js and css links` to see if they are there, I found out that only the `js link` is available, whereas the `css link` is broken. my app is not design properly due to that, clearly.

Comment: another thing(maybe related). i have added an amazon s3 hosting service to store my uploaded pictures, I don't think this is the reason for the missing css link.

Comment: Amazon has nothing to do with your stylesheet issue. You can learn about Heroku and the asset pipeline **[here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar)** as well as how to troubleshoot it. Aside from that you can **[check your logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)** to get more information.

Comment: hi deefour, I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what am I doing wrong. I am compiling my assets locally, The information is saved in the `manifest.yml` file, and they should be uploaded. what did i do differently then before and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you verified the `application.css` file is built locally as expected? Have you checked your logs after the deploy? Have you looked at the output of the deploy to see that there is no error about `application.css`? Have you checked to make sure `application.css` is not in your project or global `.gitignore`? Have you tried to make a page request in production and checked the logs then?

Comment: thank Deefour, the problem was the git ignore public/asset..ahh well rails begginers mistakes...